# How can I edit the badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, moderator-election

I saw the profile on the election page of each candidate.

I was surprised with that they have earned the edit badges. Few are **5/6** and few are **6/6**.

Here is the snap of that:

[image]

- So my question is that is it possible to edit the badges?
- How can I edit the badges?

Or want to know am I confused to understand that?

Please let me know if someone can edit the badges?

Comment: They can't edit badges.

They have earnt [badges relating to editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges).

Comment: @yivi And what is the meaning of 5 out of 6?

Comment: They've earned 5 out of 6 of the editing badges. The badges are: `Copy Editor`
`Explainer`
`Organizer`
`Refiner`
`Strunk & White`
`Tag Editor` - They are missing one of these badges if they are `5/6` and 2 if they are `4/6`. If they have `6/6` it means they have all of these badges related to editing. The same here applies to `Participation badges` and `Moderation Badges`.

Comment: How can I check that of each candidate that which one is missing? Can we?

Comment: If you have the list (see above), you can see what one they are missing through process of elimination. But there is no tooltip saying `missing Refiner` for example.

Comment: @CodeLღver you will have to go to their profile to check that..

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions

Comment: here is a little querry about the election badge for an user Id https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/697030/what-election-badge-am-i-missing?UserId=1069068

Comment: @CodeLღver you can mouse hover on the text 5/6 - it will show

Answer (score 10):

You can't edit the badges. The badge count is from their profile.

The badges it checks for are:

- Copy Editor
- Explainer
- Organizer
- Refiner
- Strunk & White
- Tag Editor

If a user is at 4/6, it means they are missing two of these badges. One badge is missing for 5/6 and they have all these badges for 6/6.

The only way to 'edit' these is to earn them and make the count go up.

The same rule applies for both moderation badges and participation badges where their badges are:

- Civic Duty
- Cleanup
- Deputy
- Electorate
- Marshal
- Reviewer
- Sportsmanship
- Steward

and

- Constituent
- Convention
- Enthusiast
- Investor
- Quorum
- Yearling

respectively.

To check what badge(s) a user is missing, you will have to go onto their profile and use process of elimination to see what is and isn't there.

Comment: To help you check what badge is missing: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/697030/what-election-badge-am-i-missing?UserId=1069068